# Handle Right Arrow on a particular row of a TDBGrid

Tags: delphi

I have a TDBGrid and data is bound to it

```
myGrid : TDBGrid;
```

Now I want to select a row of this grid and press Right Arrow, it should capture the particular cell of that row and display. Consider following grid

```
ID  Item
1   A
2   B
3   C
3   D
```

Now if I select row with ID=2, and press right arrow, a function should be called which has a statement "Showmessage(Item)"

Which event I have to fire for this?

Comment: If your question is not specific to a version of Delphi, please don't add version specific tags. This is a generic Delphi question, and the answer will apply to all versions that have a `TDBGrid`, so the only necessary tag is `delphi`.

Comment: How is the grid supposed to know that Right Arrow is supposed to show a message instead of moving to the next column in the grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's easy done, but the question is if it's a good idea doing it like desired

```
procedure TForm1.DBGrid1KeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  if Key = VK_Right then
       begin
         Showmessage(TDBGrid(sender).DataSource.DataSet.FieldByName('NAme').asString);
         Key := 0; // might or might not be wished
       end;
end;
```